# Adjective for "with the same name" / "same-way called"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I’m looking for an adjective that is similar to *eponymous* as in:

> He is playing a role of Terminator in the **eponymous** movie.

Except that it should be possible to use this adjective as a substitute for the phrase *“same-way called”* as in:

> The Luxembourg village called Shengen and the _______ [area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) located in Eurasia.

Comment: Modified the example sentence (about Shengen) so that it describes the word I am looking for better. It is not exactly the same as those, being discussed in the post, that mine is being a duplicate to.

Comment: Possibly *identically named area*, but maybe *And the area of the same name*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One sense of **homonymous** is *having the same name*.

> *homonymous* adjective
>
> ...
>
> 2. having the same name

[[Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/homonymous)]

This has already been covered on ELU when the named pair are works or people.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Did not know this word could be used in this meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the term *namesake* is what you are looking for?

*Namesake* could refer to something named after something else, which I believe is what you are searching for.

Comment: Namesake is a noun, so does not work, but thanks!